# MYSQL - Conditional Where Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

need help running a `SELECT` statement. Basically I need to use the show all values when the first value meets a certain condition.

For Example if my data is

```
ID |F ID|   DATE |   I     | II   | III   |
===========================================
1  | 11  |  1/26 | peanut  | where| Now   |
-------------------------------------------
2  | 22  |  1/26 | butter  | he   | there |
-------------------------------------------
3  | 11  |  1/27 |  jelly  | at   | he    |
-------------------------------------------
4  | 33  |  1/27 |  time   | huh  | go    |
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to be able to say something like:

```
if the first F ID = peanut
then show every ID after
```

so then my output would be

```
ID |F ID|   DATE |   I     | II   | III   |
===========================================
1  | 11  |  1/26 | peanut  | where| Now   |
-------------------------------------------
3  | 11  |  1/27 |  jelly  | at   | he    |
-------------------------------------------
```

The only thing I can think of is

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE FIRST(I='peanut')
```

Comment: **then show every ID after** - please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is quite confusing. I hope I understood it correctly.

> if the first F ID = peanut

You need to get the `F_ID` first and store it in a variable:

`SELECT @Id = F_ID FROM table WHERE I = 'peanut'`

> then show every ID after

Simply:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE F_ID >= @Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subqueries?

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `F ID`=(
  SELECT `F ID`
  FROM (
    SELECT `F ID`, `I`
    FROM `table`
    ORDER BY `ID`
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS `derived`
  WHERE `I`='peanut'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic variant with join:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  table t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      F_ID,
      date
    FROM
      table
    WHERE
      I = 'peanut'
  ) t2 ON t2.F_ID = t.F_ID AND t2.date >= t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN GET IT USING SUB QUERY 
EXAMPLE
SELECT * FROM F_VAL;

```
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID   | F_ID | DATE | I      | II    | III   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   11 | 1/26 | peanut | where | Now   |
|    2 |   22 | 1/26 | butter | he    | there |
|    3 |   11 | 1/27 |  jelly | at    | he    |
|    4 |   33 | 1/27 |  time  | huh   | go    |
|    1 |   11 | 1/25 | cake   | where | Now   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

IF YOU WANT TO GET ALL RECORD WITH THAT CONDITION

```
 SELECT * FROM F_VAL WHERE F_ID = (SELECT F_ID FROM F_VAL WHERE `I`='peanut');
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID   | F_ID | DATE | I      | II    | III   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   11 | 1/26 | peanut | where | Now   |
|    3 |   11 | 1/27 |  jelly | at    | he    |
|    1 |   11 | 1/25 | cake   | where | Now   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec))
```

IF YOU WANT TO GET ALL RECORD CREATED AFTER THE FIRST ONCE CREATED DATE

```
mysql> SELECT F.* FROM F_VAL F INNER JOIN  (SELECT F_ID,DATE FROM F_VAL WHERE `I`='peanut') X ON X.F_ID=F.F_ID AND F.DATE>=X.DATE ;
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID   | F_ID | DATE | I      | II    | III   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   11 | 1/26 | peanut | where | Now   |
|    3 |   11 | 1/27 |  jelly | at    | he    |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: in above example i have created table with name F_VAL change it according to your name

Comment: He specified that he would like this to return rows only if the first row matched the condition (that is, `I`='peanut).